# reactjs - Is it possible to pass a property to a component as following?

Tags: reactjs

wonder if it is possible to pass a component a property as following

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ContainerBox anotherComponent={<AnotherComponent />} />, document.body);
```

And then insider the `ContainerBox` I want to pass `AnotherComponent` a property in following way.

```
class ContainerBox extends React.Component {
    clickHandler() {
         //does something fun
    }

    render () {
        return (
            this.props.anotherComponent(this.clickHandler) //<----- is it possible to pass properties from here?
        );
   }
}
```

Is it possible to pass things from `ContainerBox` to `AnotherComponent` from that position?

`ContainerBox` has a `clickHandler function` which I want to pass to `AnotherComponent`. It is possible to do so if I move `<AnotherComponent />` to inside of `render()` instead. But then I cannot reuse `ContainerBox` for other components without first copying the whole `ContainerBox`.

Does it make sense? Hope you can understand.

**UPDATED** code example

Comment: No, that's impossible but you can iterate through `this.props.childer` and if it's needed component then render it

Comment: @The hmm alright, but what do you mean by iterate through the `this.props.childer` :?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. However, it's more common to do it like this

```
    ReactDOM.render(
    <ContainerBox><AnotherComponent /></ContainerBox>, document.body);
```

And in ContainerBox

```
class ContainerBox extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            this.props.children
        );
   }
}
```

Read more about reacts this.props.children here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children

#### Edit:

I just want to point out that in this example, we are not passing a component, but an element (the result of rendering the component).

It's also possible to pass components, like this:

```
<Foo buttonComponent={FancyButtonComponent} />
```

and in Foo:

```
render() {
    Button = this.props.buttonComponent;
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <Button />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: hmm, unsure if I wrote down my question good. Enough. But I want to pass `<AnotherComponent /> some new properties inside of `<ContainerBox />. I will modify my question to reflect what I mean

Comment: Cool, I just so happened to add how you can do that. To achieve what you want, you'd pass a _component class/type_, not an element (such as a rendered component).